# MS Graph Sample Application Integration Test not Working

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I want to do what the MS Graph sample node app is doing in its `integrationTests.js`, but that test doesn't work.  Here's what I've tried:

- Followed the [quick start](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/quick-start) for creating a node.js app.
- Ran the app.  Ensured it worked by sending an e-mail.
- Modified the test *Checking that the sample can send an email* to use my account parameters.
- Tried to run the test.  It fails with 403: insufficient scope.  The call to get the token returned scopes, but lacked Mail.Send.
- In the post data for the call to login.microsoftonline.com, I added "scope: 'Mail.Send'"
- I still receive a valid token, and the return scope includes Mail.Send, but when I  try to post with that token, I get 400: cannot POST /beta/me/sendMail
- I tried adding scope (Mail.Send) in the query string and as a header (thought I saw that somewhere), but it made no difference.
- I added the Mail.Send permission (under "Application Permissions") for the app in the application registration portal.
- I compared the token (using https://jwt.ms) from my test call to the call from the app when it works.  I see no real difference.  They both contain the Mail.Send scope.

Here is the code (which is only slightly different from what's in the sample):

```
// in graphHelper.js
function postSendMail(accessToken, message, callback) {
  request
   .post('https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/sendMail')
   //.post('https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/sendMail?scope=Mail.Send') // nope
   .send(message)
   .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken)
   .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
   .set('Content-Length', message.length)
   .set('scope', 'Mail.Send') // nope
   .end((err, res) => {
     callback(err, res);
   });
}

describe('Integration', function () { // mocha
  var accessToken;
  var scope;
  const config = getConfig();

  // My account variables in testConfig.json file
  function getConfig() {
    var configFilePath = path.join(__dirname, 'testConfig.json');
    return JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(configFilePath, { encoding: 'utf8' }));
  }

  function getAccessToken(done) {
    var postData = querystring.stringify(
      {
        grant_type: 'password',
        //grant_type: 'client_id',  // not supported
        //grant_type: 'authorization_code', // This assumes you've requested an auth code.
        resource: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/',
        scope: 'Mail.Send',
        client_id: config.test_client_id_v2,
        client_secret: config.test_client_secret_v2,
        username: config.test_username,
        password: config.test_password
      }
    );

    var postOptions = {
      host: 'login.microsoftonline.com',
      port: 443,
      path: '/common/oauth2/token',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(postData)
      }
    };

    var postRequest = https.request(postOptions, function (res) {
      var data = '';
      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        data += chunk;
      });
      res.on('end', function () {
        const response = JSON.parse(data);
        accessToken = response.access_token;
        scope = response.scope;
        done();
      });
    });

    postRequest.on('error', function (e) {
      console.log('Error: ' + e.message);
      done(e);
    });

    postRequest.write(postData);
    postRequest.end();
  }

  before( // eslint-disable-line no-undef
    function (done) {
      getAccessToken(done);
    }
  );
  it('Checking that the sample can send an email',
    function (done) {
      var postBody = emailer.generateMailBody(config.test_name, config.test_username);
      graphHelper.postSendMail(
        accessToken, scope,
        JSON.stringify(postBody),
        function (error) {
          assert(error === null, `The sample failed to send an email: ${error}`);
          done();
        });
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: The scope should be set before you get token, but not on doing request. So the token contains the valid/needed scope permission.

Comment: @SeiyaSu Perhaps it's not clear, but I am setting scope before getting the token and not on the request.

Comment: Note that the call to `sendMail` for v1 works (beta does not).